# Trying to register Service-Worker in separate folder

Tags: javascript, html, docker, nginx, service-worker

So I'm trying to write a Service-Worker in an external JavaScript library to intercept network requests but I'm having some issues with scoping.

In the root of my project I have index.html and scripts.js and in a folder labeled "insourcing-lib" I have my index.js and sw.js files.

In my index.js to register the Service Worker I have it as such

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("/insourcing-lib/sw.js", { scope: "/" })
    .then((reg) => {
      console.log("Service Worker Registered!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Service worker registration failed:", error);
    });
}

export {};
```

From the index.html file the path to the Service-Worker is the passed in as the first argument and the scope that I actual want to listen to network requests from is of course the index.html in root of the project so just "/". Now after doing this I get the error ->

[image: Example of error]

Now to try to fix this I created a docker container to host my files locally using nginx and set the Allow-Service-Worker header to true which is proven by the network tab after loading

[image: Example 2]

Now after this I still get the same error in the console and I'm very confused. Not sure what the fix for this would be. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Service Worker have a scope of url were they can work, and these scope can't go up except with `Service-Worker-Allowed` Header (and not `Allow-Service-Work` wich refer to nothing), in this header you can specify your desired scope `\` here.

You can see an exemple here : https://medium.com/dev-channel/two-http-headers-related-to-service-workers-you-never-may-have-heard-of-c8862f76cc60